# temporary file does not exist after calling the _tempnam function in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

i have made my code like this :

```
Public Declare Function _tempnam Lib "C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120.dll" Alias "_tempnam" (
    ByVal dir As String,
    ByVal prefix As String) As String
```

In the button click method :

```
dim pszTempName  as string = _tempnam("", "xx")
MsgBox(pszTempName)
MsgBox(My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(pszTempName))
```

The result is (as an example) :

C:\Users\Personal\AppData\Local\xx87

False

my question is why the file does not exist?

Comment: Because you haven't created the file? So far you have only declared a string that contains a file path.

Comment: to David Wilson : but the function _tempnam must create the file, why in my C++ sample , it does the job.

Comment: i did not understand you answer

Comment: please help me_____________

Comment: The dll function _tempnam only generates the name of a file that doesn't exist, not the file itself. You have to create the file. Are you trying to search for a temporary file that already exists?

Comment: but why the C++ _tempnam() fucntion create the name and the file itself?.

Comment: _tempnam only  returns the name of a file that doesnt exist in the folder you specify - Read here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355.aspx